# UK visa interview appointment for an infant is four hours later than for its parents. Can we still go together?

Tags: standard-visitor-visas

I have recently applied for a Standard Visitor visa for self, spouse and my 3-month-old infant. While my wife and I have time slots with a difference of 15 minutes apart, my child has got an appointment slot four hours later than ours.

Do I have to take my child separately later, or they allow us to take the infant with us to our interview, and process the application together?

Comment: The appointments are at Mumbai, India. I completed applications online for all 3 of us and sought appointments after making the payments. My appt is at 10.00 AM, spouse at 10.15 AM, child at 2.45 PM all at the same day.

Comment: She attends the interview with you (or your wife). They will avoid separating families wherever possible.

Comment: Sheesh, they keep lowering the age. Here I thought [three years](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/national-security/can-a-3-year-old-represent-herself-in-immigration-court-this-judge-thinks-so/2016/03/03/5be59a32-db25-11e5-925f-1d10062cc82d_story.html) for representing oneself in an immigration court is outrageous but three months, that's a new one :D

Comment: @pnuts- i carried a photo as per the visa photo guidelines for my daughter however they still asked us to get her in the biometric room. The VFS folks did not take finger prints but they did take a photo of my daughter besides the one i provided. I found it contradictory to the details mentioned on the official website where it says children under 5 are exempt from  biometrics.

Answer (score 11):

They did allow me and my wife to take our daughter in for the visa application process. However, since her interview was scheduled around 4 hours later, i had to pay INR 2560 extra to VFS to let my daughter in for the application process as a 'walk in' fees.
Alternatively, they asked me to come 4 hours later to submit  the application for my 3 month old daughter separately in case i wanted to avoid paying the fee.
There was no option to club the appointments together  for the family as per the representatives.